# deserializing json in asp.net web api

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send data from android application to asp.net web api, I have two values to send login and password, i put them in NameValuePair List and sent them. Here is my code :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", getLogin()));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword()));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(nameValuePair));
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
```

How can i deserialize the json in the web api project ?
Here is the function where I would like to deserialize the Json :

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public string login([FromBody] object data)
{
//Here I want to get the login and password values from the json.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you are making this complex? You can create simple POCO class in your WebApi as the below:

```
public class LoginModel 
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

and in your method you do the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public string login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
//loginModel.Email and loginModel.Password
}
```

and in your request you can send JSON string as the below:

```
{
  "email" : "me@mail.com",
  "password": "11111"
}
```

And leave the heavy lifting and de-serilization for WebAPI. You can do this with dictionary for sure, but using Models is better if your project grows by time

Comment: As i think i have to create LoginModel in the android project also ?

Comment: No you do not, you can send it as JSON string, try doing this first using postman.

Comment: @TaiseerJoudehthank you for mentioning postman, didn't know about this tool). Now my life will be much easier

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh How can I send it as Json from my android project ? It didn't worked when I send it in a list of NameValuePair. can you edit your answer to show me how should i do in android side ?